# Postgresql acid compliance

Tags: postgresql, transactions

When concurrent `update` is called in several `transaction` at a time, is PostgreSQL still able to maintain ACID?

Say for example if I do

```
BEGIN
  UPDATE post SET like = like + 1
  UPDATE post SET like = like + 1
END
```

multiple times concurrently all at the same time, will I see ACID compliant incrementation?

I am using `REPEATABLE READ` transaction type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, ACID will be maintained:

- Either both statements will succeed or none of them (**atomicity**).
- No constraint will be violated (**consistency**).
- The transactions will lock out each other, serialization errors reported and deadlocks resolved (**isolation**).
- After `COMMIT`, the transaction will survive a system crash as long as the transaction logs are preserved (**durability**).